# Is there a Windows PC equivalent to the OS X DigitalColor Meter?

Tags: color, software-recommendation, windows

Is there a Windows PC equivalent to the color picker app found on Mac OS X called [DigitalColor Meter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalColor_Meter)?

Comment: [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/) works great within the browser (platform independent). Also interesting: http://superuser.com/questions/255647/best-way-to-pick-a-color-from-an-image

Comment: Pixie from Nattyware is popular for this:  http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php

Answer (score 5):

I use ShareX (which is free and Open Source) as a screen grabber, it also has a "screen colour picker" in the Tools menu. It's quite nice because you can colour pick individual pixels.

It looks like this

[image: Screenshot of ShareX]

I have no affiliation with ShareX. Their website is here: https://getsharex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some. The one I use is http://www.color-picker.de/

#### Note the original site above does not work

As of December 2018 the site seems to be gone, but it seems you can still view and download a version of V4 from The Internet Archive.
https://web.archive.org/web/20181018075525/http://www.color-picker.de:80/

I was able to run the above downloaded version in a windows 10 sandbox, and it looks nice and simple, however does not allow single pixel and seems to average the pixels in a 3 x 3 area.

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered [this project](https://github.com/nagilum/dcm) which seems simple and just works. Hit the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to save the current color or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it directly as either HEX or RGB.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid installing anything, you can use Microsoft Paint. You can open a saved image in MS Paint, click the color picker (looks like an eye dropper), and click the part of the image you want the color for. Then go to Edit colors and you can see the RGB or Hue/Saturation/Lum. values.

If the color you want is not already saved as an image, you can use the built-in Snipping screenshot utility, then follow the steps above.

MS Paint enables zooming, so you can get down to the pixel you want.

Comment: ALWAYS useful to have a way of doing these things with "comes with Windows/MacOS" tools.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [Simplecolor](https://mattrajca.com/simplecolor/) recently, however it's not free.